# Bash resolve variables locally before used in a remote context

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, quoting

I've got a script that sets some environment variables on a remote machine, but I've got a problem with some variables being resolved in the remote machine's context. These variables must be resolved before being sent to the remote.

```
#!/bin/bash
devIP=$(ifconfig | sed -En \'s/127.0.0.1//;s/.*inet (addr:)?(([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*).*/\2/p')
#10.0.0.1

ssh -A ubuntu@remote '\
export variable="$devIP";\
echo $variable'
#Will echo blank as it is trying to resolve $devIP under the remote context.
```

How can I properly feed the script executor's IP into an environment variable on the remote machine?

Comment: Use double quotes instead of single quotes

Comment: Using double quotes works for echoing out devIP, but does not work for _variable_

Comment: » ssh -t ubuntu@$remotenuc 'export variable='"'$devIP'"'
quote>

That ends up being a quote error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following command

```
ssh -A ubuntu@remote "\
export variable=$devIP;\
echo \$variable"
```

Here variable substitution is performed on the local machine for variable `$devIP` in the command line argument

```
export variable=$devIP; echo \$variable
```

because of the double quotes.

Yet variable `$variable` is protected from local substitution with a backslash.

Comment: You're a genius. Exactly what I needed. Thanks

Comment: Note the `export` isn't necessary unless there are multiple subprocesses spawned on remote that need access to `variable`.